# Communication between two twin siblings components, in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this setup in my App.js:

```
<div class=container>
 <PlayerElement className="main" name="Mark" state="NY" />
 <PlayerElement className="secondary" name="Andrew" state="CA" />
</div>
```

The *PlayerElement* with className *secondary* is the same component as *main*. Only that it's hidden, and it's positioned higher and to the right on top of *main*. This is defined by their own css classes.
When you click the first *PlayerElement*, it should set its own opacity to 0.5 and *secondary* should appear. When clicked again, it should revert back to the prior state.

I'm having trouble thinking how you pass properties between two identical siblings.
I'm not sure I should arrange my app like that, or if there's a better method.

Comment: You lift the state up to the parent and control it from there by passing it **down** (*instead of across*) as props to the two `PlayerElement` components. See https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: Thank you! That's a great and useful read.
I can't choose your answer if it's on comment mode. Please submit as Answer so I can pick it if you want.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Thank you! That's a great and useful read. I can't choose your answer if it's on comment mode. Please submit as Answer so I can pick it if you want.